# SOQL for a multi select picklist on a record including any value from a list

Tags: apex, soql

Lets say on Account I have multi-select picklist field `field1` with possible values A, B, C. In my code I have `List<String> stringList = {'A', 'B'};`

I would like to have a SOQL query that gets any accounts where a value from `stringList` is in `field1`.

I have tried the following:

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE field1__c INCLUDES :stringList];
```

Comment: Off the top of my head (not checked) you probably need `... INCLUDES :String.join(stringList, ';')` or something like that. Or you may need separate `OR` conditions for each of them (since I think the INCLUDES will look for effectively AND between each...?). Someone else will be able to clarify (or test it for yourself).

Comment: this worked for me @identigral, thank you